# json dumps not including attribute name

Tags: python, json

I am writing a python lambda function that reads in a json file from s3 and then will take one of the nodes and send it to another lambda function. Here is my code:

The json snippet I want

```
"jobstreams": [
    {
      "jobname": "team-summary",
      "bucket": "aaa-bbb",
      "key": "team-summary.json" 
    }
```

**step 1 –** convert JSON to python objects for processing
note: these I got from another Stack Overflow guru - thanks!!

```
def _json_object_hook(d): return namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values())
def json2obj(data): return json.loads(data, object_hook=_json_object_hook)

routes = json2obj(jsonText)
```

**step 2 -** I then traverse the python objects and find the json I need and dump it

```
for jobstream in jobstreams:
    x = json.dumps(jobstream, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Howeever, when I print it out, I only have the values not the attributes. Why is that?

```
print(json.dumps(jobstream, ensure_ascii=False))
```

yields

> ["team-summary", "aaa-bbb", "team-summary.json"]

Comment: your "json snip" is not a valid/complete JSON

Comment: I don't see an lambda functions? what out does your script produce?

Comment: Your `object_hook=` is causing JSON objects to be loaded as Python objects that have no exact JSON equivalent.  If you just try to dump them back to JSON, of course there's going to be data loss.  You'd need to provide the opposite transformation of these objects - but that does not seem to be easily done here: `json.dumps()` does have a `default=` option that is sort of the opposite of `object_hook=`, but it only applies to objects with no JSON equivalent at all, which isn't the case for namedtuples.

Comment: thanks everyone!!  azat, yes-it was just a snip....Red Cricket, the lambda function is just getting part of the json file to start another process.. dani, your code is similar to what i have didnt want to post entire code as didnt think that would be protocol.. @Jasonharper,...hmm, I was wondering about the fancy object hook thing i am using.  candidly, i got that from another person but dont quite understand it.  it gives me the ability to create a python object with multiple trees in the json.  I tried just Json.loads and it gives me a dict error when i get to a list...  so i am stuck.

Comment: should i not use the NamedTuple technique?   How else would I create a python object sourced from a Json stream with multiple hierarchical lists and complex json structures?  any suggestions or links would be appreciated by this newbie...

Comment: It is *fundamentally impossible* for a JSON file to need anything more than just `loads()` to load it - `object_hook=` is just a convenience for converting to more specific Python types.  In your case, a plain `loads()` would give you a list of dicts rather than a list of namedtuples, that shouldn't require much of a change for your code to handle.

Comment: thanks Jason.  I ended up creating a new Dictionary from the list that the json.dumps gave me.   once i had the new dictionary (that was flat), then i converted that to json....   probably not the most efficient approach but i have other fish to fry.  THANKS to all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your full json file looks somewhat like what I have in my example

```
import json

js = {"jobstreams": [
    {
      "jobname": "team-summary",
      "bucket": "aaa-bbb",
      "key": "team-summary.json" 
    },
    {
      "jobname": "team-2222",
      "bucket": "aaa-2222",
      "key": "team-222.json" 
    }
]}

def extract_by_jobname(jobname):
    for d in js['jobstreams']:
        if d['jobname'] == jobname:
            return d


json.dumps(extract_by_jobname("team-summary")) 
# '{"jobname": "team-summary", "bucket": "aaa-bbb", "key": "team-summary.json"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new Dictionary from the list that the json.dumps gave me.

```
["team-summary", "aaa-bbb", "team-summary.json"]
```

once i had the new dictionary (that is flat), then i converted that to json.... probably not the most efficient approach but i have other fish to fry. THANKS to all for your help!